# Libgdx: how to check if there is a rectangle above current rectangle?

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, textures

I'm making an endless-runner kind of game in libgdx. I've already made terrain generator etc. but now I'm struggling with texture showing. My terrain consists of one or more layers of 64x64 rectangles. What I want to do, is show different texture if current rectangle in array looping hasn't got any other rect right above it. The  question is, how to achieve it? I tried multiple ways, but they either gave me an error or just didn't work properly :/

I'm not sure if you understood me, so here is an image of what it should look like:
[image: Texture example]

But instead, all textures that show, are the same.

Here is my current code(I know it won't work, I just don't know how to modify it now)

```
Iterator<Rectangle> brickIter = bricks.iterator();

        while(brickIter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle brick = brickIter.next();
            Rectangle newBrick = new Rectangle();
            newBrick.width = brick.width;
            newBrick.height = brick.height;
            newBrick.x = brick.x;
            newBrick.y = brick.y+brick.height;


            if(!newBrick.overlaps(brick))
                game.batch.draw(textureBricksTop, brick.x, brick.y);
            else
                game.batch.draw(textureBricks, brick.x, brick.y);
        }
```

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I managed to do this on my own. Here's the solution:

```
Iterator<Rectangle> brickIter = bricks.iterator();
    Rectangle prevBrick = new Rectangle();
    prevBrick.x = -1;

    while(brickIter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle brick = brickIter.next();

        if((prevBrick.x != -1) && (prevBrick.x != brick.x))
            game.batch.draw(textureBricksTop, prevBrick.x, prevBrick.y);
        else if(prevBrick.x != -1)
            game.batch.draw(textureBricks, prevBrick.x, prevBrick.y);

        prevBrick.width = brick.width;
        prevBrick.height = brick.height;
        prevBrick.x = brick.x;
        prevBrick.y = brick.y;
    }
```

I realised that when brick.x changes, it's new column of rectangles, because while terrain is generating, it's "for" loop for y(going up) inside loop for x(going right).

It's not perfect yet, but will do for now.